# Service Provider vs Identity Server in OAuth2 and Identity Server

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Is there is any service provider in OAuth2 and OpenId Connect? Is Service Provider and Resource server are same or different? Whats the different? I heard Service Provider in SAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is called Service Provider in SAML is called Relying Party in OpenID Connect, which is a comparable concept. OAuth 2.0 is not a federated SSO protocol like SAML is so comparing OAuth 2.0 terminology (i.e. Resource Server) with SAML doesn't work very well.

Comment: Thanks. Is Relying Party and Resource Server are same in OpenId Connect assuming that the app which is trying to login to Authorization Server and holding user resources are same?

Comment: No: that's where the confusion between OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 always starts: the Relying Party is equal to the Client of OAuth 2.0. The Resource Server is a different concept.